# Arduino RF Receiver picking up some 433MHz signals but not others

Tags: arduino, radio-transmission

I have an Arduino and a 433MHz receiver running the code below, using the RCSwitch Library. The code is working fine when I use a remote like the "BN-LINK ES1513-5-2 Wireless Remote". The bits/signal prints to the window and everyone is happy.

But when I try to pick up the signal from a dog collar(No-Shock) remote 433HMz, I get nothing.

Both remotes say they are transmitting at 433MHz.
I have multiple "BN-LINK ES1513-5-2 Wireless Remote" and I can see signal from these remotes. If i hook up another Arduino with a RF transmitter i can pick up the signal.

Any ideas why I can see signals from some but not the other?

```
#include <RCSwitch.h>

RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySwitch.enableReceive(0);  // Receiver on interrupt 0 => that is pin #2
}

void loop() {
  if (mySwitch.available()) {
    output(mySwitch.getReceivedValue(), mySwitch.getReceivedBitlength(), mySwitch.getReceivedDelay(), mySwitch.getReceivedRawdata(),mySwitch.getReceivedProtocol());
    mySwitch.resetAvailable();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transmitting at 433 Mhz is only one part of the infrastructure, the other issue is at what protocol the transmission is done and that would probably be different from a remote control to a dog collar.

In the ReadMe section of the [rc-switch library](https://github.com/sui77/rc-switch) you can find a list of supported chipsets. EV1527 for example is one of the common and can be found on many the low-cost 433Mhz devices including remote controls. You could look for information about that, however, to my opinion, if you are to use a device/chipset/protocol supported by this lib, you should no longer worry about low-level communication.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know of any links, articles, additional info that would talk about some of the common protocols used?

Comment: Added info to original answer